# populate parse-server schema with swagger

Tags: swagger, parse-server, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I'd like use swagger to define a schema/API for parse-server. While I'm new to parse server I'm not sure where to start or even if this is a right approach to import a swagger generated schema to parse-server which can be then updated/extended.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for general advice. You may be best off looking for a tutorial series on how to use parse-server.

Comment: actually I'm asking for a very specific advice - how to combine `parse-server` and `swagger`. Regular tutorials do not cover what can be the approach to populate parse schema from external source (i.e. swagger)

Comment: I think you would need to roll your own solution. There doesn't look like there are any existing libraries which would do this for you.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: From my research writing some generator is needed.
Also my schema did not get that complex - had almost no cloud code and the schema is pretty CRUD-ish most o the time and I found it pretty easy to relay on parse auto create feature. 
OTOH I started to struggle more with UI state management and so decided to shift toward GraphQL - integrating apollo with parse is just few lines of code and then it's matter of provide resolvers and mutators and while the initial costs are not negligible you quickly benefit from having GQL schema and having client not depending on underlying backend.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/bhtz/parse-server-swagger it generates swagger spec from parse schema. May need some update though!